# How do I add text to curved image?

Tags: php, image, gd

```
$config['source_image'] = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
$config['wm_text'] = 'Copyright 2006 - John Doe';
$config['wm_type'] = 'text';
$config['wm_font_path'] = './system/fonts/texb.ttf';
$config['wm_font_size'] = '16';
$config['wm_font_color'] = 'ffffff';
$config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
$config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
$config['wm_padding'] = '20';

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);

$this->image_lib->watermark();
```

This is water mark code in php, it is working fine when we add text to curve image like mug
image, the letter is not overlap the curved image how can we overcome?

Comment: I don't understand sh*t! Maybe a little more rephrasing / sample code / example images would **help you**?

Answer (score 1):

You added this to your code:

```
$config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
$config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
```

So I guess it won't overlap the corners, unless the text is as long/wide as the image itself, so that it reaches the corners. Maybe change the padding `wm_padding` so that it's as wide or wider than the curve/border radius?

And like Alix Axel said, please post some relevant code for more detailed/usable answers.